# Comparing a String to a List of Words

Tags: vb.net, string-comparison

I'm trying to implement a search function in a program I am writing. At the moment, I have a list of strings which I am searching through.

What I'd like to do is check whether *all* words that have been typed into a search box appear in the search results. However, the catch is that they can appear in any order. So for example, if the string is:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

and I were to type:

> dog fox brown

It would return a positive match.

My first thought was to `.split` the words in the search box into an array. Then, iterate through the list of strings, and check to see if the string contained every word in the array, else, remove it from the list. Once all the strings have been iterated through, display the results.

However, I can imagine that there would be a significant amount of overhead, especially because I'd like the filtering to be done real-time, ie. attached to the TextChanged event of the textbox.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this filtering? I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't a more efficient way of doing this before I started coding it.

Comment: If you were to split and iterate over the items, you should order both collections before doing so, then you could apply a smarter algorithm instead of checking every item...

Comment: Hi @Alisson. Do you mean  splitting both strings, sorting the resulting arrays and then doing an array comparison?

Comment: The [**`HashSet` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) could come in handy here. Unlike a list, you don't need to iterate the entire `HashSet` just to see if a certain item is present (thus saving you a lot of processing power). Just call [**`HashSet.Contains()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) and the Framework will take care of the lookup for you.

Comment: @VisualVincent interesting, didn't know the hashset would be able to do that in that way, using a `Contains()` function. I thought it would work only when checking for equality.

Comment: @Alisson : That depends on what you mean by _equality_. The OP needs to add every word to the `HashSet` at first, then iterate every word of the _**input**_ and check if the `HashSet` contains it.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. Using a `HashSet` is only profitable if you can build one for each string _beforehand_. Otherwise your initial thought is one of the fastest, @Aommaster.

Comment: @VisualVincent Noted! Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose `Regex.Matches().Count` in a Linq `.Select().Sum()`

Given the provided input string:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Counts the number of patterns that are a match in that string and the number of patterns (words).

Given the patterns contained in the string: (and assuming that the separator character is `chr(32)`)

> dog fox brown

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim words As Integer
Dim NumberOfMatches As Integer = GetMatchingWords(
                                 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
                                 "dog fox brown",
                                 words)


Public Function GetMatchingWords(TextToSearch As String, WordsToMatch As String, ByRef words As Integer) As Integer

    words = Regex.Matches(WordsToMatch, ChrW(32)).Count + 1
    Return WordsToMatch.Split(ChrW(32)).Select(
           Function(word) Regex.Matches(TextToSearch, word).Cast(Of Match)().Count()).Sum()
End Function
```

This Function returns:

```
words = 3
NumberOfMatches = 3<br>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make a small optimization on this. The `words = Regex.Matches(WordsToMatch, Chr(32)).Count + 1` is not required inside the function, since the search term is the same. So I moved that out. Not sure if it would make a significant difference but I figured why not.

Comment: Well, I added that count in the edit you see. I wasn't sure if you wanted to compare the number of words to the number of matches. Or if you needed that numeric reference at some point. If you don't, less code is better :)

Comment: Noted! Thank you very much!